# Voltage drop in function of electric field and current distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

For a wire, the voltage drop $\Delta V$ over a length $l$ of the wire is given by $\Delta V = \int\limits_l \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}$ with $\mathbf{E}$ the electric field. How to calculate this voltage drop for a wire with a specific current distribution $I(\mathbf{r})=I\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r})$ inside the wire? Is it correct to write

$$\Delta V = \int\limits_A \int\limits_l \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot d\mathbf{l} dA = \int\limits_V \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot \mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r}) dr^3 $$
with $A$ the wire cross-section, $V$ the entire volume and $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{r})$ the electric field density (electric field per unit cross-section)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that a static current $\vec{J}(\vec{r})$ does not imply necessarily a voltage drop, you need an electric field to make a voltage drop according to the equation
$$
\Delta V= -\int_{\gamma} \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{l}
$$
if you have only the current you need a match between $\vec{J}$ and $\vec{E}$ for example resistivity
$$
\rho \vec{J}=\vec{E}
$$

Answer (score -1):

Voltage between two points of space is magnitude of difference in potentials at those points. This difference can also be expressed as integral of **conservative electrostatic part** of total electric field:

$$
\varphi_2 - \varphi_1 = \int_1^2 - \mathbf E_{C}(\mathbf x) \cdot d\mathbf x.
$$

This integral depends only on the endpoints and does not depend on the path between, so voltage is also function of the endpoints only.

This integral is the general expression for voltage in terms of electrostatic field, there is no current density and in general, no reason to involve it.

In a special case where the path used is entirely in an ohmic conductor (metal) and total electric field inside is non-vanishing electrostatic field (so inside there is a stationary current density), one can use Ohm's law

$$
\mathbf j = \sigma \mathbf E_C
$$
to express the electrostatic field $\mathbf E_C$ in terms of current density, so potential difference can be expressed in terms of current density as
$$
\varphi_2 - \varphi_1 = \int_1^2  -\frac{1}{\sigma} \mathbf j \cdot d\mathbf x.
$$

Comment: Note that the voltage is really defined as the path integral of the _total_ electric field, not just of the conservative part. See e.g. the IEC definitions for [voltage](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=121-11-27) and [potential difference](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=121-11-26). The first line may cause a bit of confusion between the two concepts.

Comment: That paragraph's definition of voltage is indeed implying voltage is integral of total electric field. It is quite a common idea, but when compared to a large body of consistent and successful literature on workings of AC electric circuits, it desintegrates. According to this incorrect definition, voltage depends on the path chosen, and voltage across a perfect inductor is zero when the path goes through the coils of the inductor, in direct contradiction with established practice in describing and analyzing RLC circuits, where voltage drop across perfect inductor is always $LdI/dt$.

Comment: Ján, the literature on workings of AC electric circuits uses exactly that definition, with the total electric field (source: it's my field). In fact, voltage depends on the path chosen in AC, and this is an issue e.g. in the definition of impedance (see e.g. L. Callegaro, _Electrical Impedance: Principles, Measurement, and Applications_, CRC press, 2013). The voltage across an inductor is $LdI/dt$ with the definition with the total electric field, see e.g. R. M. Fano, L. J. Chu, and R. B. Adler, _Electromagnetic fields, energy, and forces_, MIT Press, 1968.

Comment: Put another way, a voltmeter really measures the integral of the _total_ electric field along the interconnecting wires and passing through the voltmeter. See e.g. https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.12923

Comment: Voltmeter indeed measures total EMF through its wiring, not voltage. There is a great difference between EMF and voltage. The definition of voltage based on total electric field does not give $LdI/dt$ because total electric field in coils of perfect inductor vanishes.

Comment: Voltage drop between two points is path independent property of two points in AC circuits. Otherwise Kirchhoff's voltage law (the modern version with voltage drops) does not hold. The only way one can get path independent voltage is to use electrostatic part of the field.

Comment: No, a voltmeter really measures the voltage. I give up trying convincing you, but I really suggest you to read the literature that I cited, and especially Fano's book, to better understand these concepts and the limits of Kirchhoff's laws.

Comment: Can you point me to a specific section of Fano or other source that shows integral of total electric field is $LdI/dt$?

Comment: Section 6.8 of Fano, but the whole chapter 6 is dedicated to deriving, in an in-depth way, Kirchhoff's laws for time-varying fields and the constitutive relationships for the basic elements.

Comment: OK I'll take a look. Meanwhile you can ponder on why precise realtime voltage measurements in high frequency electronics take so much care about proper bonded wiring and preventing loops. My understanding is they do it because they are not interested in "integral of total electric field" at all, but are interested in integral of electrostatic part of this field.

Comment: Making accurate voltage measurements in low- and high-frequency electronics is actually part of my everyday job, and no, the reason is not that one. You want to prevent loops because around loops the line integral of the electric field depends on the loop and the voltage is thus ill-defined, and it's sufficient to move a cable to change the reading.

Comment: This is the reason why one uses coaxial circuits in AC: in a coaxial circuit with a TEM electromagnetic field, the voltage is well defined at every cross-section of the circuit, provided that one really ensures coaxiality (this can be done by an appropriate use of so-called current equalizers).

Comment: But that is what I am talking about. You just concurred that "voltage" defined as path-dependent integral of total electric field is not well defined! This quantity is not what we are interested in when we are measuring voltage on some component terminals. Meanwhile integral of electrostatic field is exactly what we are interested in, because it does not depend on the path, only endpoints; it reflects spatial distribution of charges nearby and gives correct values consistent with lumped component model, where *voltage between two terminals* is well defined quantity.

Comment: No, we are interested exactly in that quantity, but in AC what we do is to measure that path-dependent quantity along a well-defined and reproducible path.

Comment: Note also that like it or not, a voltmeter measures that path-dependent quantity and therefore you cannot choose to measure the integral of the electrostatic field. You can only define boundary conditions for the electromagnetic field so that you can measure the voltage across a well-defined path.

Comment: You are confusing voltage and EMF. Your voltage concept across ideal inductor is always zero.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not confusing anything: I pointed you to the literature, and it's more than 20 years that I make these kind of measurements and I verify the theory almost every day. Therefore, I give up.

Comment: I have checked Fano section 6.8 and that section is an incoherent mess. They implicitly assume total field vanishes in the conductor so the coil is perfect conductor, analyze its fields, derive formula for difference of potential that is based on conservative field (which is correct and fine with me) but then they put up surprising statements like *"The possibility of defining a terminal voltage for a coil in a reasonably unique manner rests just on the fact that $\mathbf{E}_1'$, the field produced by the charges, is conservative and, in practical cases, much larger than $\mathbf {E}_1$"*.

Comment: That statement is a non-sequitur there and I believe it is incorrect in general. First, if the field $\mathbf E_1'$ was conservative self-induction could not happen. If it happens, that field isn't conservative. Second, in practical cases of dense winding the field $\mathbf E_1'$ is stronger than the field $\mathbf E_1$ only outside the conductor. Inside, in their case of perfect conductor, they are the same magnitude and cancel each other. But the latter is the case whatever density of the winding. So there is no such problem to their derivation; it is valid for any perfect conducting coil.

Comment: Their calculation of potential drop across perfect inductor in 6.156 is based on the idea that there is electric potential defined by integral of some conservative field from one terminal to another. That part they got right, they do not claim that potential drop is integral of total electric field.

Comment: I appreciate that you took the time to have a look at the book. Their definition of voltage, which is given on p. 256 and in section 6.10, is based on the _total_ electric field, not on the conservative part. What they say is that if the non-conservative part is negligible, then one can have a voltage approximately independent of the path, otherwise one should choose a suitable path. See also the discussion in this paper, which reports also an experiment showing how the definition works: https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.12923.

Comment: See also [this book](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-002-electromagnetic-field-theory-a-problem-solving-approach-spring-2008/textbook-contents/), section 6.2.3. You can go on thinking that your definition is the right one, but anyone working in the field defines the voltage as the integral of the _total_ electric field, because _voltmeters measure that quantity_. And physicists and engineers experimented this in a variety of ways (for instance, in the various definitions of impedance).